Magento 2 I want to update product weight and price on add to cart with custom options
I have two custom options on the product view page: width and length. When adding a product to the cart, I want to update both the weight and the price based on these options.
Currently, the price update works correctly. However, the weight update behaves unexpectedly. Here's the issue:

When a product is added to the cart for the first time, the weight is updated correctly based on the custom options.

If I select a different set of custom options and add the same or another product to the cart, the new product's weight is updated correctly, but the previous product's weight resets to its original value.


My Approach
I’ve used several events and plugins to achieve this functionality:
Events Used:
checkout_cart_product_add_after
quote_item_save_before
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
sales_quote_item_set_product
Plugins Used:
Target Classes:
Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem
Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item
Methods Intercepted:
aroundAddProduct
beforeSetQty
beforeAddProduct
aroundSetProduct
Please provide the proper way to update the weight of a product dynamically based on custom options when added to the cart, ensuring that:

The weight is updated correctly for the newly added product.
The previously added items in the cart retain their updated weight without reverting.
Thank you!

Plugin code
namespace Vendor\module\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
class CustomPricePlugin
{
protected $request;
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 */
public function __construct(RequestInterface $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * Around plugin for calcRowTotal
 *
 * @param AbstractItem $subject
 * @param callable $proceed
 * @return void
 */
public function aroundCalcRowTotal(AbstractItem $subject, callable $proceed)
{
    // Call the original method to calculate default row total
    $proceed();

    // Check if the item is new (has no ID yet)
    if ($subject->getId()) {
        return; // Skip updating weight for existing items
    }

    // Retrieve the custom parameters
    $customParams = $this->request->getParams();

    if (!isset($customParams['options']) || !is_array($customParams['options'])) {
        return; // If options are missing, return without modifying the weight
    }

    $firstTwoValues = array_values(array_slice($customParams['options'], 0, 2));

    if (count($firstTwoValues) < 2) {
        return; // Return if width or length is missing
    }

    $width_mm = (float)$firstTwoValues[0];
    $length_mm = (float)$firstTwoValues[1];

    // Get product price per square meter
    $product = $subject->getProduct();
    $price_per_m2 = $product->getPrice();

    // Get original product weight
    $originalWeight = $product->getWeight();

    // Calculate the total price based on dimensions
    $originalPrice = $price_per_m2;
    $diffPrice = $subject->getPrice() - $originalPrice;
    $totalPrice = $this->calculatePrice($width_mm, $length_mm, $originalPrice);
    $actualPrice = $totalPrice + $diffPrice;

    // Set the custom price
    $subject->setCustomPrice($actualPrice);
    $subject->setOriginalCustomPrice($actualPrice);
    $subject->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

    // Optional: Recalculate row total with the custom price
    // $subject->setRowTotal($actualPrice * $subject->getQty());
}

/**
 * Calculate price based on width, length, and price per m²
 *
 * @param float $width_mm
 * @param float $length_mm
 * @param float $price_per_m2
 * @return float
 */
public function calculatePrice($width_mm, $length_mm, $price_per_m2)
{
    // Convert width and length from millimeters to meters
    $width_m = $width_mm / 1000;
    $length_m = $length_mm / 1000;

    // Calculate total price
    $total_price = ($width_m * $price_per_m2) + ($length_m * $price_per_m2);

    return $total_price;
}

/**
 * Calculate weight based on width, length, and weight per m²
 *
 * @param float $width_mm
 * @param float $length_mm
 * @param float $weight_per_m2
 * @return float
 */
public function calculateWeight($width_mm, $length_mm, $weight_per_m2)
{
    // Convert width and length from millimeters to meters
    $width_m = $width_mm / 1000;
    $length_m = $length_mm / 1000;

    // Calculate total weight
    $total_weight = ($width_m * $weight_per_m2) + ($length_m * $weight_per_m2);

    return $total_weight;
}

}
this function calculateWeight i use to update weight but when update the weight previous item weight comes in its original weight

share the code into question which you try for update weight.

Code added and also update the question
